# How do I concatenate a list of strings in F#?

Tags: f#

I'm trying this at the moment, but I haven't quite got the method signature worked out... anyone? messages is a field of seq[string]

```
let messageString = List.reduce(messages, fun (m1, m2) -> m1 + m2 + Environment.NewLine)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but

```
let strings = [| "one"; "two"; "three" |]
let r = System.String.Concat(strings)
printfn "%s" r
```

You can do

```
let strings = [ "one"; "two"; "three" ]
let r = strings |> List.fold (+) ""
printfn "%s" r
```

or

```
let strings = [ "one"; "two"; "three" ]
let r = strings |> List.fold (fun r s -> r + s + "\n") ""
printfn "%s" r
```

Comment: I went for the fold option. Not the most concise but I'm trying different things to get the hang of the language... thanks

Comment: or just `Seq.fold (+) ""` for the third way.  benefit over `reduce` is that you won't get a "The input sequence was empty" exception if it is empty

Answer (score 49):

```
> String.concat " " ["Juliet"; "is"; "awesome!"];;
val it : string = "Juliet is awesome!"
```

Comment: This is the way to go, note String here refers to the F# Core.String library which is imported by default: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353761.aspx

Comment: ["Juliet"; "is"; "awesome!"] |> String.concat " ";;

Answer (score 5):

I'd use String.concat unless you need to do fancier formatting and then I'd use StringBuilder.

```
(StringBuilder(), [ "one"; "two"; "three" ])
||> Seq.fold (fun sb str -> sb.AppendFormat("{0}\n", str))
```

Answer (score 2):

just one more comment,

when you are doing with string, you'd better use standard string functions.

The following code is for EulerProject problem 40.

```
let problem40 =
    let str = {1..1000000} |> Seq.map string |> String.concat ""
    let l = [str.[0];str.[9];str.[99];str.[999];str.[9999];str.[99999];str.[999999];]
    l |> List.map (fun x-> (int x) - (int '0')) |> List.fold (*) 1
```

if the second line of above program uses fold instead of concat, it would be extremely slow because each iteration of fold creates a new long string.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.String.Join(Environment.NewLine, List.to_array messages)
```

or using your fold (note that it's much more inefficient)

```
List.reduce (fun a b -> a ^ Environment.NewLine ^ b) messages
```

Comment: I'm sure a StringBuilder would be faster than a concatenation algorithm.

Comment: Yes, that's why I called the 2nd solution inefficient - relying on String.Join/concat using a StringBuilder internally.

Comment: @Dario, what is the purpose of using ^ and Env.NewLine instead of + and "\n" ?

Comment: Isn't ^ the operator for string concatenation? I used Env.Newline because it was used in the question.

Comment: Right it is. I thought it was for OCaml cross-compiling purpose only.

Comment: I don't know OCaml but I consider it as a bad practice to use (+) for non-arithmetic purpose.

Comment: My bad Dario, I didn't know that System.String.Join uses StringBuilder.  Makes sense it would.