# This expression was expected to have type string

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, f#, string-concatenation

I am trying to merge values from 5 textboxes in to a string to display in a label. However I am getting this error message

```
This expression was expected to have type string but here has type string -> string -> string -> string -> string
```

I can show the anyone textbox value into the label. 
Here is the code I as using:

```
let temp = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.Temp @>, "")
let ph = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.PH @>, "")
let soil = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.SOIL @>, "")
let slope = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.SLOPE @>, "")
let aspect = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.ASPECT @>, "")

let display = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.Display @>, "")

let goCommand = self.Factory.CommandSyncParam(fun param -> self.Display <- sprintf "The data that has been enter is:\n%s,\n %s,\n %s,\n %s,\n %s" param)

member x.TEMP with get() = temp.Value and set value = temp.Value <- value
member x.PH with get() = ph.Value and set value = ph.Value <- value
member x.SOIL with get() = soil.Value and set value = soil.Value <- value
member x.SLOPE with get() = slope.Value and set value = slope.Value <- value
member x.ASPECT with get() = aspect.Value and set value = aspect.Value <-value
member x.Display with get() = display.Value and set value = display.Value <- value
member x.GoCommand = goCommand
```

I found this code [How do I concatenate a list of strings in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779048/how-do-i-concatenate-a-list-of-strings-in-f) and  this is what output that I want. So I tried the this code with with my values.

```
let strings =["temp.Value"; "ph.Value"; "soil.Value"]

let r = strings |> List.fold (fun r s -> r + s + "\n") ""

printfn "%s"
```

I got this as the output:

```
temp.Value
ph.Value
soil.Value
```

So how do you get the Value of each category to show up and how to merge it to the "let goCommand?"

edited per request to showing the xaml code

```
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding TEMP}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding PH}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding SOIL}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding SLOPE}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding ASPECT}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,0,16,0" />
    <Button Margin="0,31,0,652" Grid.Row="8" FontSize="16" Content="Submit" Foreground="DarkBlue" FontWeight="Heavy" Background="LightBlue"
        Command="{Binding GoCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding TEMP, PH, SOIL,SLOPE, ASPECT}"/>
```

Comment: If you don't need to change the variables to display from the code (Temp, PH, SOIL,...), it is easier to combine them into one record.

Comment: @FoggyFinder added the xaml code.

Comment: For the future: xaml is not F# - using `,` in bindings you don't create a tuple of these elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties (x.TEMP,...) are available from the MainViewModel - you don't need to try to transfer their values as a parameter. So you need to use the command without any parameters:

.xaml:

```
    <Button Margin="0,31,0,652" Grid.Row="8" FontSize="16"
     Content="Submit" Foreground="DarkBlue" FontWeight="Heavy" 
Background="LightBlue" Command="{Binding GoCommand}" />
```

.fs:

```
let display = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.Display @>, "")

let go() = 
    self.Display <- sprintf "The data that has been enter is:\n%s,\n %s,\n %s,\n %s,\n %s" 
        self.TEMP self.PH self.SOIL self.SLOPE self.ASPECT

let goCommand = self.Factory.CommandSync(go)
```

**Edit:**

Full .fs:

```
type MainViewModel() as self = 
    inherit ViewModelBase()    

    let temp = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.TEMP @>, "")
    let ph = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.PH @>, "")
    let soil = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.SOIL @>, "")
    let slope = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.SLOPE @>, "")
    let aspect = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.ASPECT @>, "")

    let display = self.Factory.Backing(<@ self.Display @>, "")

    let go() = 
        self.Display <- sprintf "The data that has been enter is:\n%s,\n %s,\n %s,\n %s,\n %s" 
            self.TEMP self.PH self.SOIL self.SLOPE self.ASPECT

    let goCommand = self.Factory.CommandSync(go)

    member x.TEMP with get() = temp.Value and set value = temp.Value <- value
    member x.PH with get() = ph.Value and set value = ph.Value <- value
    member x.SOIL with get() = soil.Value and set value = soil.Value <- value
    member x.SLOPE with get() = slope.Value and set value = slope.Value <- value
    member x.ASPECT with get() = aspect.Value and set value = aspect.Value <-value
    member x.Display with get() = display.Value and set value = display.Value <- value
    member x.GoCommand = goCommand
```

Comment: I am getting these errors: <br> The field, constructor or member 'Display' is not defined --and--- Unexpected identifier in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.--and--Incomplete value or function definition. If this is in an expression, the body of the expression must be indented to the same column as the 'let' keyword.

Comment: @Aaron M, We can continue to chat to quickly resolve the question? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f

Comment: I am in the room but how to use it

Comment: glad to help. If you have any more questions - just make ping.